# Problems using hand-made transformation functions

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions

I experience difficulties when using custom transformation rules. Below I give two concrete problems. I am interested in fixing each of them and in understanding what is wrong with my attitude to the issue in general.

1) Suppose I try to make symbolic computations involving gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ more effective. Particularly, I want $\it{Mathematica}$ to make use of the property $\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z)}=z$ in simplification, which it doesn't do on its own. Evaluation of

```
Simplify[Gamma[z + 1]/Gamma[z]]
```

returns

```
Gamma[1 + z]/Gamma[z]
```

In order to handle this task let me define the first transformation function

```
tf1[e_] := e /. Gamma[x_]/Gamma[y_] /; Simplify[x - y] == 1 :> y;
```

Now evaluation of

```
 Simplify[Gamma[z + 1]/Gamma[z], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1}]
```

indeed gives

```
z
```

However, execution of

```
Simplify[Gamma[z + 1]^2/Gamma[z]^2, 
TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf1}]
```

results in no real simplification and gives

```
Gamma[1 + z]^2/Gamma[z]^2
```

Well, one unwitty way to deal with this problem is to define a separate transformation function for the ratio of squares. But the ratio of the third powers will then require a third transformation function and so on. I would like to handle all these possibilities universally.

I've tried something like

```
tfUniversal[e_] := 
e /. (Gamma[x_]/Gamma[y_])^n_ /; Simplify[x - y] == 1 :> y^n;
```

but this didn't work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

2) The second chapter of my adventures includes teaching "Mathematica" identity $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}$. Here problem comes right at the start. I define transformation function

```
tf2[e_] := 
e /. Gamma[x_] Gamma[y_] /; Simplify[x + y] == 1 :> Pi/Sin[Pi x];
```

and then evaluate

```
Simplify[{Gamma[-z] Gamma[1 + z], Gamma[z] Gamma[1 - z]}, 
TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf2}]
```

which gives

```
{-\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] z], Gamma[1 - z] Gamma[z]}
```

so that simplification occurs in the first case but not in the second. I wonder what is the problem here.

Overall, I am very often troubled with such issues. Is it possible to find some references in the literature on using custom transformation rules?

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Would `FullSimplify[Gamma[z + 1]/Gamma[z]]` help ?

Comment: Dear b.gatessucks, thank you for this point. I wasn't aware that the difference between `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` is important here. However, the question basically remains since `FullSimplify` won't work for some other functions (e.g. `BarnesG` which satisfies `BarnesG[z+1]/Barnes[z]=Gamma[z]`).

Comment: I appreciate that gamma functions are just an example here, but as a point of interest there is also ``Developer`GammaSimplify`` which will attempt to reduce the number of gamma functions even if the resulting expression is more complex, e.g. ``Developer`GammaSimplify[Gamma[z+4]/Gamma[z]]``

Comment: @ Simon Woods I looked up at commands of the Developer package. It is stays there in the Section "Details" that the functions like GammaSimplify and others are automatically used by FullSimplify. Could you please kindly comment, why you find that using this package is advantageous with respect to FullSimplify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your rule for tfUniversal is *almost* correct, and I fixed it up by inspecting objects via FullForm.

```
FullForm[Gamma[z]^2/Gamma[z + 1]^2]
(* Times[Power[Gamma[z],2], Power[Gamma[Plus[1,z]],-2] *)
```

while the pattern in your rule has FullForm

```
FullForm[(Gamma[x_]/Gamma[y_])^n_]
(* Power[Times[Gamma[Pattern[x,Blank[]]],
               Power[Gamma[Pattern[y,Blank[]]],-1]], Pattern[n,Blank[]]]]*)
```

The important difference is your rule has `Power` on the outside, exponentiating the ratio, while the quantity you had tried to simplify was a `Times` of two `Power`s.

I made a working `tfUniversalNew` by following the expression you're interested in:

```
tfUniversalNew[e_] := e /. (
        (Gamma[x_]^p_. Gamma[y_]^q_.) :> Gamma[x]^(p + q) y^(-q) /; And[Simplify[x - y] == 1, p q < 0]
    )
```

The `p q < 0` ensures that you have a ratio.  Now

```
Simplify[Gamma[z + 1]^7/Gamma[z]^2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfUniversalNew}]
```

gives

```
z^2 Gamma[1 + z]^5
```

I think similar FullForm inspection can help you create other rules for cases of interest...

Comment: This is quite instructive and useful, thank you!

Comment: You should use `_.` patterns for the powers `p` and `q` or it will fail for `Gamma[z + 1]/Gamma[z]`.

Comment: Indeed!  Thanks for catching that.  I will put it in the answer.

Comment: Also: you can omit the `p q < 0` if you don't mind simplifying eg. `Gamma[z + 1]^7 Gamma[z]^2` to `Gamma[z + 1]^9 / z^2`

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
Simplify[Gamma[z+1]^2/Gamma[z]^2, 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Simplify`SimplifyGamma, Automatic}]
(* z^2 *)
```

or

```
FullSimplify[Gamma[z+1]^2/Gamma[z]^2]
(* z^2 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after posting I've found the answer to the second question and decided to put it here while the first question still remains unresolved.

The thing is that I expected $\it{Mathematica}$ to give

```
-\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] (1 - z)]
```

when evaluating

```
Simplify[Gamma[z] Gamma[1 - z], 
TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf2}]
```

but the `LeafCount` of the latter expression is actually less the that of the former. So $\it{Mathematica}$ does not render it as a simplification and therefore does not apply transformation.

A way to avoid it is to use some expression with a low `LeafCount` in the transformation function, e.g.

```
tf2simpler[e_] :=
```

e /. Gamma[x_] Gamma[y_] /; Simplify[x + y] == 1 :> simple[y];

and making a replacement rule

```
replacement = simple[y_] :> Pi/Sin[Pi y];
```

then, evaluation of

```
Simplify[{Gamma[-z] Gamma[1 + z], Gamma[z] Gamma[1 - z]}, 
TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf2simpler}] /. replacement
```

Gives the desirable answer.

```
{\[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] (1 + z)], \[Pi] Csc[\[Pi] z]}
```